# AngularJS - Unable to use Factory Method inside Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependency-injection, angularjs-factory

I'm having a problem when trying to inject `myFactory` into `myDirective`. I need `myfactory.myMethod` to get a dynamic `templateUrl` based on a certain event.

That's what I'm trying right now:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', ['myFactory', function (myFactory) {

      var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl : function(myFactory){
          if(myFactory.myMethod()){
            return '/app/hello.html'
          }
          return '/app/world.html'
        },
        controller       : 'MyController',
        controllerAs     : 'myCtrl',
        bindToController : true
      };

      return directive;

    }]);

})();
```

I get the following error

> myFactory.myMethod is not a function

I tried looking at various solutions also on SO but I wasn't able to find the proper one.

`myFactory` is a simple Factory

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('myFactory', function () {

      function myMethod() {
       . . .
      }

      //Or
      var myMethod = function(){
       . . .
      }

      return {
        myMethod: myMethod
      }

    });
})();
```

**How can I fix this?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show code of factory `myFactory`.

Comment: Done, but it isn't a matter of wrong factory. I don't just find a proper way to inject a Service/Factory into a directive using this directive definition.

Comment: can you show to where are you defining/injecting myApp ? this are separate files? are they load as the time the directive loads? aside of that one thing that you can improve `var myMethod = function(){ .... } ;`

Comment: the injection is fine, the problem came from another thing, I edited my previously comment can you check the new things

Comment: I first inject Factories and Services, then Directives. I made that with `Gulp`. My App module definition looks like `(function(){ 'use strict'; angular.module('myApp', [modules . . .]);  })();`

Comment: Looks like `myFactory` not loaded in browser. Check it in *console->network*.

Comment: It gets loaded. I also tried injecting directives before factories but nothing changes.

Comment: I somehow managed to correctly inject the Factory but now I get `myFactory.myMethod is not a function`. I update the question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have  given us. I would suggest to really check if the file that contains myFactory is loaded in browser.

Comment: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/400NEK9tXcXTFMuQmWLr?p=preview)

Comment: Don't really know. It seems like it's getting imported correctly.

Comment: May be it due to the fact that in `myMethod` I call another factory method? I mean, something to do with `Async`? I tried using `Promises` into that particular piece of code but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your mistake, that is you passed the service as a parameter in function that return template url `templateUrl : function(myFactory){}`. It's totally wrong, you cannot use it as a parameter.

To correct it, you need to remove `myFactory` parameter in the set templateUrl function, like that:

```
templateUrl : function(){
  if(myFactory.myMethod()){
    return '/app/hello.html'
  }
    return '/app/world.html'
  }
```

And I see your code is missing creating module: `angular.module('myApp', []);`

Try yourself in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/nguyentk90/pen/wzBdjj).

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: You are totally right. It was a poor error. +1 and Accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: About the code missing, it does not miss, I have it in a separated file.